# Mail is sending as localhost from Ubuntu server

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ubuntu, ssmtp

Hello I am sending a mail from my server.

If I run it directly on the server I get a proper url but when the cronjob is processed the url is with local host.
I am using CodeIgniter framework running on Ubuntu 13.04 with ssmtp

This is my encode :

```
$yes = site_url('job/itemExtend/?id=' . urlencode($this->encrypt->encode($itemid)));
$no = site_url('job/itemFree/?id=' . urlencode($this->encrypt->encode($itemid)));
```

My cronjob:

```
10 0 * * * php /var/www/TakeAway/index.php job checkTakeAways
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses separate ini files depending on the environment :

- php.ini
- cli/php.ini
- cgi/php.ini

Make sure you have configured them all correctly to specify the  option